# Terminilogy for AC/DC classification

Tags: terminology

For example if you wanted to created a datasheet with an item specifying that the device requires AC power, what would that item be called. My first thought is current type but that does not seem right.

Comment: `power requirement` or `power supply`

Answer (score 2):

- Voltage. [AC/DC]
- Current. [AC/DC] or [Alternating/Direct]
- AC/DC. [AC/DC]

Any one of the above options would suit.

Answer (score 2):

That's practically always absorbed in the supply voltage specifications (rarely in the current specifications, because there's more devices that want a voltage supply with a minimum current capacity, than the other way around:

For DC, typically:

> 12 VDC

or

> ⎓ 12 V.

For alternating current devices,

> 48 VAC

or, to also specify the AC frequency,

> 120 V 60 Hz

or, if your device typically depends on peak-to-peak voltage,

> 144 Vpp

or, if root mean square is an important measure (e.g. because your voltage isn't sinusoidal), or if your there's a DC offset in your voltage:

> 10 Vrms

Not as pretty, but still sometimes seen, and quite clear:

> 100 V~

Could also be, not very common, but hey, there's a unicode codepoint called "SINE WAVE = alternating current":

> ∿100 V